# PHP, MySQL Unicode Issue

Tags: php

I am having problems displaying Unicode like "★", it wont insert into the database, it just shows up as "â˜… ", however when I do it directly in PHPMyAdmin it works fine, so I don't think its the MySQL database I think its something to do with PHP. Wondering if anyone knows the cause and a way to fix it?

Comment: Show us the code of page. Won't able to know the issue without code.

Comment: Alok, I don't see why code would be needed as its processing a string... Also Jamie I looked at what you linked and that's doing it for the database, my database isn't the problem.

Comment: @jdne: Yes, it does have to do with the database...or rather the way you insert into the database. Think again. Look at your code, since we're not able to.

Answer (score 0):

use HTML Special Characters for ★

```
&#9733;
```

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: jdne should be able to insert unicode in the database.